# Why is OS X creating two bash processes per tab?

Tags: macos, bash

So when I have 3 tabs open, `ps aux | grep bash` reports:

```
$ ps aux | grep bash

root        629   0.0  0.0  2486024   4812 s002  Ss    8:01pm   0:00.02 login -pf moon /bin/bash
moon        513   0.0  0.0  2434460   2508 s001  S+    8:01pm   0:00.07 -bash
root        512   0.0  0.0  2496264   4884 s001  Ss    8:01pm   0:00.02 login -pf moon /bin/bash
moon        381   0.0  0.0  2434460   2500 s000  S+    8:00pm   0:00.09 -bash
root        379   0.0  0.0  2498312   4920 s000  Ss    8:00pm   0:00.03 login -pf moon /bin/bash
moon        740   0.0  0.0  2432768    620 s002  R+    8:01pm   0:00.00 grep bash
moon        630   0.0  0.0  2434460   2500 s002  S     8:01pm   0:00.07 -bash
```

Why is this happening?

**EDIT: Rendering the processes as a tree**

```
 | |-+= 04939 moon /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal -psn_0_2322999
 | | |-+= 04942 root login -pf moon /bin/bash
 | | | \-+= 04943 moon -bash
 | | |   \-+= 05051 moon man login
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that it's not *two bash processes*: It's one `bash` process, and one `login` process with options.

This is how Apple implemented the various startup options for new windows and tabs, e.g. whether to use the default or current shell's working directory, or whether to launch the default shell or a specific one.

You'll notice that when you change these options in Terminal's preferences, the `login` command's arguments change a bit.

If you set every option to *default*, except the working directory of a new tab, and change the working directory of the current tab, then the new tab's shell will be opened by `login -pfl danielbeck /bin/bash -c exec -la bash /bin/bash` instead of `login -pf danielbeck`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question. Is it the `login` process that is forcing bash to start as a "login shell"? How does it manage to do so?

Comment: @0xcafebabe Either it's `login` *without* the `-l` argument, or it's `bash`'s `exec` command *with* the `-l` argument. See the respective `man` pages for what these arguments do.